# как изменить формат времени pandas

Tags: python, pandas

мне нужно получить разницу времени e_UTC - s_UTC в колонке "Video_duraction"  как бы явно я не задавал тип, получается такой формат -

> 0 days 00:29:59
> 0 days 00:29:59

Как мне убрать эти "0 days"   ?

```
fix_columns = ["Folder_Name", "Date", "UTC", "s_KP", "e_Date", "e_UTC", "e_KP", "Video_duraction"]
df = pd.DataFrame(res_dict)
                
df["UTC"] = df["UTC"].astype("datetime64")
df["e_UTC"] = df["e_UTC"].astype("datetime64")
        
df["Video_duraction"] = (df['e_UTC'] - df["UTC"])
         
df["UTC"] = pd.to_datetime(df["UTC"]).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df["e_UTC"] = pd.to_datetime(df["e_UTC"]).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                
KP_start = round(float(res_dict["KP"][0]),3)
KP_end = round(float(res_dict["KP"][-1]),3) 
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sec_to_format(s):
    h,s = divmod(int(s),3600)
    m,s = divmod(s,60)
    return f'{h:02}:{m:02}:{s:02}'

df['Video_duraction'] = [sec_to_format(s) for s in df['Video_duraction'].dt.total_seconds()]
```